# Using dplyr and across to compute multiple dot products

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe that takes the form

```
set.seed(100)
n = 1000
data = data.frame(
  y1_a = rnorm(n),
  y1_b = abs(rnorm(n)),
  y2_a = rnorm(n),
  y2_b = abs(rnorm(n))
)
```

I would like to compute the dot products y1_a * y1_b, as well as y2_a * y2_b.

I am able to compute the element wise products using `mutate` and `across` like this

```
data %>%
  mutate(
    (across(ends_with("a"), .names = '{.col}_b_dp') * across(ends_with("b")))
  )
```

This generates 2 extra columns called "y1_a_b_dp", and "y2_a_b_dp". But these are the element wise products, not the dot products. So these columns need to be summed in order to produce the dot product.

But I am curious, is there a way to use summarise with 2 references to across

```
data %>%
  summarise(
    colSums(across(ends_with("a"), .names = '{.col}_b_dp') * across(ends_with("b")))
  )
```

This almost works. It computes the elementwise products as 2 columns, then does colSums to compute 2 dot products. However, the return value sent back to summarise is a dataframe with 2 rows, which dplyr complains about. I want the return value sent to summarise to be 2 columns instead, like in the manual construction of mutate and sum. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one approach using `reframe` and a small convenience function for the sake of readability:

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

dp <- function(x, y) {
  data.frame(
    t(colSums(x * y))
  )
}

data %>%
  reframe(
    dp(
      across(ends_with("a"), .names = "{.col}_b_dp"),
      across(ends_with("b"))
    )
  )
#>   y1_a_b_dp y2_a_b_dp
#> 1  57.31544 -15.33576
```

Comment: I really like the use of this auxiliary function. It makes this double `across` trick much more readable. +1!

Comment: Thx @Maël. Learned this trick from you. And it still amazes me that it works. :D

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach:

```
data %>%
  reframe(
    across(ends_with("a"), ~sum(. * get(gsub("a","b",cur_column()))),.names = '{.col}_b_dp') )

  y1_a_b_dp y2_a_b_dp
1  57.31544 -15.33576
```